# Karma gives me errors when running tests (related to backbone.js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, backbone.js, karma-runner

My error is related to backbone.js `'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '_.each')` it's pointing to line 227 which is inside my test.js script which was compiled by browserify.

This line is a built-in block within backbone, so the actual issue can't be within that line obviously.

So my setup... I am testing a simple module here, it's Inside `./client/src/views/`.

```
// intro.js

var Backbone = require('backbone');

module.exports = IntroView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.intro',
    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.height($(window).height() - 10);
    }
});
```

Then I have the actual test module inside `./client/spec/views/`

```
// intro.test.js

var IntroView = require('../../src/views/intro.js'),
    $ = require('jquery');

describe('view:intro', function() {
    var introView = new IntroView();

    it('just testing if I can get a success', function() {
        expect(1 + 2).toEqual(3);
    });

    it('should render the view', function() {
        introView.render();
    });
});
```

Okay so I run `gulp browserify` to compile the script like this

```
gulp.task('browserify:tests', function() {
    return gulp.src('./client/spec/views/intro.test.js')
        .pipe(tasks.browserify({
            transform: ['hbsfy', 'browserify-shim']
        }))
        .pipe(tasks.concat('tests.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./test'));
});
```

Then inside my `karma.config.js`

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({

        // base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
        basePath: '',


        // frameworks to use
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],

        // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
        files: [
            './test/tests.js',
        ],


        // list of files to exclude
        exclude: [

        ],


        // test results reporter to use
        // possible values: 'dots', 'progress', 'junit', 'growl', 'coverage'
        reporters: ['progress'],


        // web server port
        port: 9876,


        // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
        colors: true,


        // level of logging
        // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


        // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
        autoWatch: false,


        // Start these browsers, currently available:
        // - Chrome
        // - ChromeCanary
        // - Firefox
        // - Opera (has to be installed with `npm install karma-opera-launcher`)
        // - Safari (only Mac; has to be installed with `npm install karma-safari-launcher`)
        // - PhantomJS
        // - IE (only Windows; has to be installed with `npm install karma-ie-launcher`)
        browsers: ['PhantomJS'],


        // If browser does not capture in given timeout [ms], kill it
        captureTimeout: 60000,


        // Continuous Integration mode
        // if true, it capture browsers, run tests and exit
        singleRun: true
    });
};
```

Lastly I run `karma start` in the command line. So I hope I am using karma the right way, I think I am but if I want to test my code which uses backbone I need to get past this hump.

So my question is what am I doing wrong, why is the error occurring within the backbone.js code? Also am I doing it the right way?

Comment: What is your `requirejs` config looks like?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, but it was caused by using modules `map`ing in my `requirejs` config. I've solved it by using `paths` instead (i've overwrite my browser config).

Your problem is most likely that you didn't have `requirejs` config. See [`requirejs` config page](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/plus/requirejs.html) for further instructions.